# Pygame block sprites not being drawn on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I'm very new to python and pygame and I was trying to make a top-down shooter style game. I managed to get many components working but I cant get the blocks that I shoot at to show up in the rooms I created in the game. I moved the code for it to the game function and it shows up on screen but when you move between rooms they stay the same, for the time being I commented that part out. I want each room to have their own blocks that I can shoot, but when I try putting the code into each room class it does not show up on the screen. I'm pretty sure nothing is drawn over it. I want to know why the walls are being drawn but not the blocks. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pygame, sys, math, random
 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
click = False

# Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

# Create an 800x600 sized screen
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])

# Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Maze Runner')
 
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
 
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Make a BLUE wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(color)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Set speed vector
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
 
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
 
    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y
 
    def move(self, walls):
        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
 
        # Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of
            # the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
 
        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
 
        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
 
            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, dest_x, dest_y):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Set up the image for the bullet
        self.image = pygame.Surface([5, 5])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
        # Move the bullet to our starting location
        self.rect.x = start_x
        self.rect.y = start_y
 
        # Because rect.x and rect.y are automatically converted
        # to integers, we need to create different variables that
        # store the location as floating point numbers. Integers
        # are not accurate enough for aiming.
        self.floating_point_x = start_x
        self.floating_point_y = start_y
 
        # Calculation the angle in radians between the start points
        # and end points. This is the angle the bullet will travel.
        x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        y_diff = dest_y - start_y
        angle = math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff);
 
        # Taking into account the angle, calculate our change_x
        # and change_y. Velocity is how fast the bullet travels.
        velocity = 5
        self.change_x = math.cos(angle) * velocity
        self.change_y = math.sin(angle) * velocity
 
    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
 
        # The floating point x and y hold our more accurate location.
        self.floating_point_y += self.change_y
        self.floating_point_x += self.change_x
 
        # The rect.x and rect.y are converted to integers.
        self.rect.y = int(self.floating_point_y)
        self.rect.x = int(self.floating_point_x)
 
        # If the bullet flies of the screen, get rid of it.
        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > WIDTH or self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()
 
class Room(object):
    # Each room has a list of walls, and of enemy sprites.
    wall_list = None
    enemy_sprites = None
    block_list = None
 
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor, create our lists. """
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()    
        self.block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.movingsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
 
class Room1(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Make the walls. (x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
 
        # This is a list of walls. Each is in the form [x, y, width, height]
        walls = [[0, 0, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [0, 350, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [780, 0, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [780, 350, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [20, 0, 760, 20, WHITE],
                 [20, 580, 760, 20, WHITE],
                 [390, 50, 20, 500, BLUE]
                ]
 
        # Loop through the list. Create the wall, add it to the list
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
        
        for i in range(10):
            # This represents a block
            block = Block(GREEN)
            # Set a random location for the block
            block.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - 50)
            block.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - 50)
            # Add the block to the list of objects
            self.block_list.add(block)
            self.movingsprites.add(block)      
 
class Room2(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        walls = [[0, 0, 20, 250, RED],
                 [0, 350, 20, 250, RED],
                 [780, 0, 20, 250, RED],
                 [780, 350, 20, 250, RED],
                 [20, 0, 760, 20, RED],
                 [20, 580, 760, 20, RED],
                 [190, 50, 20, 500, GREEN],
                 [590, 50, 20, 500, GREEN]
                ]
 
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
            
        block = Block(RED)
        block.rect.x = 200
        block.rect.y = 200
        self.block_list.add(block)
        self.movingsprites.add(block)
 
 
class Room3(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        walls = [[0, 0, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [0, 350, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [780, 0, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [780, 350, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [20, 0, 760, 20, PURPLE],
                 [20, 580, 760, 20, PURPLE]
                ]
 
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
 
        for x in range(100, 800, 100):
            for y in range(50, 451, 300):
                wall = Wall(x, y, 20, 200, RED)
                self.wall_list.add(wall)
 
        for x in range(150, 700, 100):
            wall = Wall(x, 200, 20, 200, WHITE)
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
 
def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def main_menu():
    done = False
    while not done:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 20, True, False)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        draw_text('main menu', font, WHITE, screen, 20, 20)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button_1 = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 200, 50)
        if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                game()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, button_1)
        
        draw_text('Play', font, WHITE, screen, 60, 110)

        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True   
            
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        
    pygame.quit()

def game():
    # Create the player paddle object
    player = Player(50, 50)
    movingsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    movingsprites.add(player)
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
    wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    
    #for i in range(10):
        ## This represents a block
        #block = Block(GREEN)
        ## Set a random location for the block
        #block.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - 50)
        #block.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - 50)
     
        ## Add the block to the list of objects
        #block_list.add(block)
        #movingsprites.add(block)    
 
    rooms = []
 
    room = Room1()
    rooms.append(room)
 
    room = Room2()
    rooms.append(room)
 
    room = Room3()
    rooms.append(room)
 
    current_room_no = 0
    current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
    done = False
 
    while not done:
 
        # --- Event Processing ---
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, -5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, 5)
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                        done = True
 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, 5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, -5)
                    
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
                # Get the mouse position
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                mouse_x = pos[0]
                mouse_y = pos[1]
                # Create the bullet based on where we are, and where we want to go.
                bullet = Bullet(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, mouse_x, mouse_y)
                # Add the bullet to the lists
                movingsprites.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)            
 
        # --- Game Logic ---
 
        player.move(current_room.wall_list)
        movingsprites.update()
 
        if player.rect.x < -15:
            if current_room_no == 0:
                current_room_no = 2
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
            elif current_room_no == 2:
                current_room_no = 1
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
            else:
                current_room_no = 0
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
 
        if player.rect.x > WIDTH + 1:
            if current_room_no == 0:
                current_room_no = 1
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 0
            elif current_room_no == 1:
                current_room_no = 2
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 0
            else:
                current_room_no = 0
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 0
                
        for bullet in bullet_list:
            # See if it hit a block
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
            # For each block hit, remove the bullet and add to the score
            for block in block_hit_list:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                movingsprites.remove(bullet)
            # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
            if bullet.rect.y < -10:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                movingsprites.remove(bullet)    
 
        # --- Drawing ---
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        
        block_list.draw(screen)
        movingsprites.draw(screen)
        current_room.wall_list.draw(screen)
 
        pygame.display.flip()
 
        clock.tick(60)
 
    pygame.quit()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_menu()
```

Sorry about the long code, this is my first time asking a question here. Once again any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the blocks list a property of the room class, and then draw them in draw. Notice how in draw, I call

```
current_room.block_list.draw(screen)
```

So is this what you mean:

```
import pygame, sys, math, random
 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
click = False

# Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

# Create an 800x600 sized screen
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])

# Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Maze Runner')
 
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
 
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Make a BLUE wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(color)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Set speed vector
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
 
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
 
    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y
 
    def move(self, walls):
        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
 
        # Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of
            # the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
 
        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
 
        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
 
            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, dest_x, dest_y):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Set up the image for the bullet
        self.image = pygame.Surface([5, 5])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
        # Move the bullet to our starting location
        self.rect.x = start_x
        self.rect.y = start_y
 
        # Because rect.x and rect.y are automatically converted
        # to integers, we need to create different variables that
        # store the location as floating point numbers. Integers
        # are not accurate enough for aiming.
        self.floating_point_x = start_x
        self.floating_point_y = start_y
 
        # Calculation the angle in radians between the start points
        # and end points. This is the angle the bullet will travel.
        x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        y_diff = dest_y - start_y
        angle = math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff);
 
        # Taking into account the angle, calculate our change_x
        # and change_y. Velocity is how fast the bullet travels.
        velocity = 5
        self.change_x = math.cos(angle) * velocity
        self.change_y = math.sin(angle) * velocity
 
    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
 
        # The floating point x and y hold our more accurate location.
        self.floating_point_y += self.change_y
        self.floating_point_x += self.change_x
 
        # The rect.x and rect.y are converted to integers.
        self.rect.y = int(self.floating_point_y)
        self.rect.x = int(self.floating_point_x)
 
        # If the bullet flies of the screen, get rid of it.
        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > WIDTH or self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()
 
class Room(object):
    # Each room has a list of walls, and of enemy sprites.
    wall_list = None
    enemy_sprites = None
    block_list = None
 
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor, create our lists. """
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()  
        self.block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.movingsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
        for i in range(10):
            # This represents a block
            block = Block(GREEN)
            # Set a random location for the block
            block.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - 50)
            block.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - 50)
         
            # Add the block to the list of objects
            self.block_list.add(block)
            self.movingsprites.add(block)   
 
 
class Room1(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Make the walls. (x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
 
        # This is a list of walls. Each is in the form [x, y, width, height]
        walls = [[0, 0, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [0, 350, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [780, 0, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [780, 350, 20, 250, WHITE],
                 [20, 0, 760, 20, WHITE],
                 [20, 580, 760, 20, WHITE],
                 [390, 50, 20, 500, BLUE]
                ]
 
        # Loop through the list. Create the wall, add it to the list
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
        
        for i in range(10):
            # This represents a block
            block = Block(GREEN)
            # Set a random location for the block
            block.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - 50)
            block.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - 50)
            # Add the block to the list of objects
            self.block_list.add(block)
            self.movingsprites.add(block)     
 
class Room2(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        walls = [[0, 0, 20, 250, RED],
                 [0, 350, 20, 250, RED],
                 [780, 0, 20, 250, RED],
                 [780, 350, 20, 250, RED],
                 [20, 0, 760, 20, RED],
                 [20, 580, 760, 20, RED],
                 [190, 50, 20, 500, GREEN],
                 [590, 50, 20, 500, GREEN]
                ]
 
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
            
        block = Block(RED)
        block.rect.x = 200
        block.rect.y = 200
        self.block_list.add(block)
        self.movingsprites.add(block)
 
 
class Room3(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        walls = [[0, 0, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [0, 350, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [780, 0, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [780, 350, 20, 250, PURPLE],
                 [20, 0, 760, 20, PURPLE],
                 [20, 580, 760, 20, PURPLE]
                ]
 
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
 
        for x in range(100, 800, 100):
            for y in range(50, 451, 300):
                wall = Wall(x, y, 20, 200, RED)
                self.wall_list.add(wall)
 
        for x in range(150, 700, 100):
            wall = Wall(x, 200, 20, 200, WHITE)
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
 
def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def main_menu():
    done = False
    while not done:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 20, True, False)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        draw_text('main menu', font, WHITE, screen, 20, 20)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button_1 = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 200, 50)
        if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                game()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, button_1)
        
        draw_text('Play', font, WHITE, screen, 60, 110)

        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True   
            
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        
    pygame.quit()

def game():
    # Create the player paddle object
    player = Player(50, 50)
    movingsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    movingsprites.add(player)
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
    wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    
    rooms = []
 
    room = Room1()
    rooms.append(room)
 
    room = Room2()
    rooms.append(room)
 
    room = Room3()
    rooms.append(room)
 
    current_room_no = 0
    current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
    done = False
 
    while not done:
 
        # --- Event Processing ---
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, -5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, 5)
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                        done = True
 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, 5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, -5)
                    
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
                # Get the mouse position
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                mouse_x = pos[0]
                mouse_y = pos[1]
                # Create the bullet based on where we are, and where we want to go.
                bullet = Bullet(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, mouse_x, mouse_y)
                # Add the bullet to the lists
                movingsprites.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)         
 
        # --- Game Logic ---
 
        player.move(current_room.wall_list)
        movingsprites.update()
 
        if player.rect.x < -15:
            if current_room_no == 0:
                current_room_no = 2
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
            elif current_room_no == 2:
                current_room_no = 1
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
            else:
                current_room_no = 0
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
 
        if player.rect.x > WIDTH + 1:
            if current_room_no == 0:
                current_room_no = 1
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 0
            elif current_room_no == 1:
                current_room_no = 2
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 0
            else:
                current_room_no = 0
                current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
                player.rect.x = 0
                
        for bullet in bullet_list:
            # See if it hit a block
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
            # For each block hit, remove the bullet and add to the score
            for block in block_hit_list:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                movingsprites.remove(bullet)
            # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
            if bullet.rect.y < -10:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                movingsprites.remove(bullet)    
 
        # --- Drawing ---
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        
        current_room.block_list.draw(screen)
        movingsprites.draw(screen)
        current_room.wall_list.draw(screen)
 
        pygame.display.flip()
 
        clock.tick(60)
 
    pygame.quit()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_menu()
```

Also, if you change the collision detection to this:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
            # See if it hit a block
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, current_room.block_list, True)
```

It will detect bullet hits against the rooms blocks

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe something so simple was able to frustrate me as much as it did, goes to show how much I need to learn. Once again thank you!

Comment: @Cloudi no worries, glad to help.  Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes as you get to a point where you can't see the wood for the trees. Nice job so far on the game, keep it up!